# how to get the appointmentId for a meeting created through EWS, then use it to update later

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying microsft's EWS api service to handle the meeting requests. But Now I want to update the times for a previous meeting created in EWS. 
I cant really find a way to do that.

```
Appointment meeting = Appointment.Bind(service, meetingId, new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, 
                                                                       AppointmentSchema.Location, 
                                                                       AppointmentSchema.RequiredAttendees, 
                                                                       AppointmentSchema.Resources));
```

The above code is picked up from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495610(v=exchg.150).aspx

I have no idea what appointmentId means there. How do I get that.

Comment: Sorry for short mistake avove. But it is: I have no idea what meetingId means there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the EWSId (ItemId) of the Appointment you want to access https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd634072(v=exchg.80).aspx . You need to using FindItems (or FindAppointment) to find the existing appointment and bind to this and update it eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx or using a SearchFilter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579422%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Cheers
Glen

Comment: I found a very compact answer too. When you create a meeting in outlook server it actually stores meeting id reference to that meeting. And when one needs to update it, that meeting id can be used to update.